# Template email on mobile does not display correctly

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have problem with styling email on mobile.
I want to put an image on the border of some container.
Because it is an email, I cannot use any `position:absolute` or negative margin.
I found a nice example that works well on emails on desktops http://jsfiddle.net/dkmf7hso/
but it breaks on an email on mobile device (image goes to the left)
Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: _"On mobile"_ is too vague term. Each email client is very different and this code will not work on most of them (you can test your email on Litmus etc. - beware of older Outlook). One of the main problems is that your styles are not inline - most clients supports only inline styles. Btw you can try to re-build it in some framework, for example [MJML](https://mjml.io/), it will solve a lot of email-related-problems for you.

Comment: It is not about inline style, because when testing on Litmus I can choose option " Move my CSS inline when I click Send Email"

Comment: It's an advanced trick, but you may be able to get something following this https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position